# Prestashop 1.6., TM HTML Content at TopRight

Tags: prestashop

I create a new `TM HTML` Content  and I want to place it at Top right; actually I can just display it in the centre of the Top area.

How can I place it at top right?

[www.oledia.fr](http://www.oledia.fr)

Comment: you should be able to do that via `displayBanner` hook

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and
["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Formatting changes

Comment: @popeye Thank you for your answer; please can you explain more or give me a link for additional information. because i cannot figure it out.